# Searching for content post

Tags: functions, search, the-content

I need the "wordpress search" engine to be only for the content of the posts.
I looking for some solution but always "wordpress search" engine only shows results by titles of the post.
What can I modify or what should I do to solve this problem?
Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 3):

Stright from Wordpress reference:

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_search/#user-contributed-notes

You can search by *post title only* with:

```
function __search_by_title_only( $search, $wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;
    if(empty($search)) {
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query
    }
    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
    $n = !empty($q['exact']) ? '' : '%';
    $search =
    $searchand = '';
    foreach ((array)$q['search_terms'] as $term) {
        $term = esc_sql($wpdb->esc_like($term));
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }
    if (!empty($search)) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if (!is_user_logged_in())
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter('posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2);
```

If you wanted to search by *post content only,* you'd change the above slightly, and do:

```
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
```